# Error says no package.json, but it is in current directory

Tags: node.js, angular, web, npm, npm-install

Hi I am receiving the following error when trying to install any packages using npm install using the command npm install "package name":

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\abecker\Documents\Git-ng2-Admin\file:..\has-unicode\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! package.json ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'C:\Users\abecker\Documents\Git-ng2-Admin\file:..\has-unicode\package.json'
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\abecker\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-06-21T03_36_11_730Z-debug.log
```

I have a package.json file within the root folder(Git-ng2-Admin). However, according to the error it says it needs to go to Git-ng2-Admin\file:..\has-unicode\ to find the json file, which is incorrect.  Is there a way to reconfigure where the package.json file is supposed to be searched for?

edit:  added the package.json file as requested

```
{
"name": "ng2-admin",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "Angular and Bootstrap 4 Admin Template.",
"author": "Akveo <contact@akveo.com>",
"homepage": "http://akveo.github.io/ng2-admin/",
"repository": {
  "type": "git",
"url": "git+https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin.git"
},
"bugs": {
  "url": "https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin/issues"
},
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "rimraf": "rimraf",
  "changelog": "standard-changelog",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "start:hmr": "ng serve --hmr",
  "start:aot": "ng serve --aot",
  "start:prod": "ng serve --prod",
  "start:prod:aot": "ng serve --prod --aot",
  "build": "npm run clean:dist && ng build",
  "build:prod": "npm run build -- --prod",
  "build:prod:aot": "npm run build:prod -- --aot",
  "build:ci": "npm run build:prod && npm run build:prod:aot",
  "build:demo": "npm run build:prod:aot -- --base-href \"http://akveo.com/ng2-admin/\"",
  "test": "ng test -sr",
  "test:coverage": "npm run clean:coverage && ng test -sr -cc",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "lint:styles": "stylelint ./src/app/**/*.scss",
  "lint:ci": "npm run lint && npm run lint:styles",
  "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
  "e2e": "ng e2e",
  "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
  "clean:coverage": "npm run rimraf -- coverage",
  "docs:deploy": "wintersmith build -C docs && gh-pages -d docs/build",
  "docs:serve": "wintersmith preview -C docs"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "4.1.3",
  "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
  "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
  "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
  "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
  "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
  "@angular/platform-server": "4.1.3",
  "@angular/router": "4.1.3",
  "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.26",
  "@ngx-translate/core": "6.0.1",
  "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "0.0.3",
  "amcharts3": "github:amcharts/amcharts3",
  "ammap3": "github:amcharts/ammap3",
  "angular2-datatable": "0.6.0",
  "animate.css": "3.5.2",
  "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",
  "chart.js": "1.1.1",
  "chartist": "0.10.1",
  "chroma-js": "1.3.3",
  "ckeditor": "4.6.2",
  "core-js": "2.4.1",
  "easy-pie-chart": "2.1.7",
  "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
  "fullcalendar": "3.3.1",
  "google-maps": "3.2.1",
  "ionicons": "2.0.1",
  "jquery": "3.2.1",
  "jquery-slimscroll": "1.3.8",
  "leaflet": "0.7.7",
  "leaflet-map": "0.2.1",
  "lodash": "4.17.4",
  "ng2-ckeditor": "1.1.6",
  "ng2-completer": "1.3.1",
  "ng2-handsontable": "0.48.0",
  "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "4.0.0",
  "ng2-smart-table": "1.2.1",
  "ng2-tree": "2.0.0-alpha.5",
  "ngx-uploader": "2.2.5",
  "normalize.css": "6.0.0",
  "roboto-fontface": "0.7.0",
  "rxjs": "5.4.0",
  "zone.js": "0.8.11"
},
"devDependencies": {
 "@angular/cli": "1.1.2",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
  "@types/fullcalendar": "2.7.40",
  "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
  "@types/jquery": "2.0.41",
  "@types/jquery.slimscroll": "1.3.30",
  "@types/lodash": "4.14.61",
  "@types/node": "6.0.69",
  "codelyzer": "3.0.1",
  "gh-pages": "0.12.0",
  "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
  "karma": "1.4.1",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
  "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.2.0",
  "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
  "npm-run-all": "4.0.2",
  "protractor": "5.1.0",
  "rimraf": "2.6.1",
  "standard-changelog": "1.0.1",
  "stylelint": "7.10.1",
  "ts-node": "2.1.2",
  "tslint": "5.2.0",
  "tslint-eslint-rules": "4.0.0",
  "tslint-language-service": "0.9.6",
  "typescript": "2.3.2",
  "typogr": "0.6.6",
  "underscore": "1.8.3",
  "wintersmith": "2.2.5",
  "wintersmith-sassy": "1.1.0"
},
"main": "karma.conf.js",
"directories": {
  "doc": "docs"
}
}
```

Comment: What are the dependency in your `package.json`? Is it referring to has-unicode?

Comment: post package.json in question

Comment: This is only the path issue. `ENOPACKAGEJSON` says the package json file does not have the file either does not match to your current terminal path. Tip to workout will be match both the path of terminal as well as project path were your package Json exists

Comment: How do I update the terminal path to go where the package.json file is located? @mayur

Comment: Each package must have its package.json. The error does not complain about yours, but about `has-unicode`

Comment: @LorenzMeyer has-unicode is located within my node modules and contains a package.json file

Answer (score 3):

Removing `package-lock.json` before attempting `npm install` again resolved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After a quick search, found this [bug](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17081).

Finally ended up finding a strange entry in package-lock.json:

```
"has-unicode": {
  "version": "file:file:..\\has-unicode",
  "integrity": "sha1-o82Wwwe6QdVZxaLuQIwSoRxMLsM=",
  "dev": true
},
```

and removing it solved my problem.